# Simple IF sequence in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am working with creating a dynamic sql stored procedure in MYSQL. My problem is really simple but I couldn't run it after hours! Please help me if I've mistaked something.

```
 DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_job_list(
  IN id VARCHAR(10) CHAR SET utf8,
  IN job_title VARCHAR(50) CHAR SET utf8,
  IN qualify VARCHAR(50) CHAR SET utf8
)
BEGIN
    SET @s = 'SELECT * FROM wp_sho_jobrequirment WHERE 1 = 1 ';
    IF job_title <> NULL AND job_title <> ''  
        THEN 
            SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ' AND job_title LIKE %', job_title, '%'); 
        END IF;
    IF qualify <> NULL AND qualify <> '' 
       THEN
            SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ' AND qualify LIKE %', qualify, '%'); 
       END IF;
    IF id <> NULL AND id <> '' 
        THEN  
           SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ' AND id =', id); 
        END IF;

    SELECT @s;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

My main problem, I think, is with `if` statement where I didn't write `THEN END IF` clauses at first but it doesn't work with some compile error! Then when I put clauses I compiled but not work!
When I use this code to call the stored procedure IF statement not act so nothing append to my dynamic sql query:

Call SP:

```
SET @p0=''; SET @p1='f'; SET @p2='f'; CALL `sp_job_list`(@p0, @p1, @p2);
```

Dynamic Query String At Result:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_sho_jobrequirment WHERE 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your results are due to incorrect usage of the `<>` operator against `NULL`.
`<>` means `Not equal`. You can't directly apply it on `NULL` values.
Instead use `IS NOT` to compare with `NULL`.

The statement

```
IF job_title <> NULL AND job_title <> ''
```

should be

```
IF job_title IS NOT NULL AND job_title <> ''
```

**Similarly**:

**Change** `IF qualify <> NULL AND qualify <> ''`
**To** `IF qualify IS NOT NULL AND qualify <> ''`

And

**Change** `IF id <> NULL AND id <> ''`
**To** `IF id IS NOT NULL AND id <> ''`

***Refer to Documentation***: [**Not Equal ( <> )**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

> != (or <>) doesn't see NULL as something that can be compared to and
>   thus doesn't compare itself to those records that have the field
>   marked null.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'd wrote `IS NOT NULL` before but I had some error. Then I change it to `<>` . But now I found `IS NOT NULL` is correct and my problem was removing `THEN..END IF` from `IF` statement! Is it neccessary to be in `IF` clause with one statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is comparing the null value ,Yo should use **'is null'** to check the value null .

```
 IF job_title is null and job_title <> ''  
            THEN 
                SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ' AND job_title LIKE %', job_title, '%'); 
            END IF;
        IF qualify is null AND qualify <> '' 
           THEN
                SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ' AND qualify LIKE %', qualify, '%'); 
           END IF;
        IF id is null AND id <> '' 
            THEN  
               SET @s = CONCAT(@s, ' AND id =', id); 
            END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks Assen. I should use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `IS NULL`